# LINQ to Entities ne reconnaît pas la méthode 'System.Decimal Parse(System.String)'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

In my SQL SERVER I have a field Poids (type: Varchar) and when I tried to convert it to Decimal I had this error: "LINQ to Entities ne reconnaît pas la méthode 'System.Decimal Parse(System.String)'" .
This my code:

```
  var list = db.Réception.Where(y => y.Supprimée == false).
                Select(x => new
                {
                    Id_rec = x.Id_rec,
                    N° = x.N°,
                    Date_rec = x.Date_rec.ToString(),
                    heure_rec = x.heure_rec.ToString(),
                    Qualité = x.Qualité.Qualité1,    
                    Poids = x.Wg.AsEnumerable().Where(y => y.Id_rec == x.Id_rec).Select(w => decimal.Parse(w.Poids)).Sum(),
                    Nbwg =x.Wg.Where(y => y.Id_rec == x.Id_rec).Count()    
        });
```

Please if someone can help me I'm blocked and I tried some solutions in web but without results.

Comment: You need to materialize the query - `var list = db.Réception.Where(y => y.Supprimée == false).ToList().Select(....`

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bentity-framework%5D+or+%5Bentity-framework-6%5D+LINQ+to+Entities+does+not+recognize

Comment: @StephenMuecke,  I tried that but I got an error : System.NullReferenceException
La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.

Comment: This is an English only site. And it did solve your error (you just have another one as well)

Comment: please translate it to English, it will be  easy to get more help or easy to communicate with you.

Comment: Sorry,the error is:  "System.NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance of an object"  Thanks in advance .

Comment: Linq ne sait pas traduire en SQL la méthode Parse, d'où l'erreur. Peux-tu poster ton code qui te donne l'erreur actuelle ? - Linq is unable to translate Parse C# method into SQL. Can you post code giving you "NullReferenceException" ?